# Perfis de usuário para acesso em API REST utilizando NodeJS + ORM SequelizeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, sequelize-js

Existe uma forma, ou algum pacote bacana, para trabalhar com perfis de usuário para acesso em determinados *endpoints* da API REST, conforme permissão de cada um? Estou utilizando NodeJS + Express + SequelizeJS como ORM.

Comment: Olá! Estou utilizando o [express-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt) para isso, e funciona perfeitamente. Abraço e boa sorte!

Comment: Pesquise por ACL (Access Control List) que é exatamente o que vc precisa para isso.
https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=acl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valeu ajuda pessoal, consegui bem o que queria usando o package [Express-ACL](http://github.com/andela-thomas/express-acl), serviu muito bem, funciona perfeitamente!